# in tcl script, exec make check RUNTESTFLAGS="compile.exp --target_board=atmega128-sim" doesn't work

Tags: tcl

I am trying to run the gcc testsuite using a driver script in tcl.
When  i write

```
if {[catch {exec make check RUNTESTFLAGS="compile.exp --target_board=atmega128-sim"} errmsg ]} {
    puts "Test finished with failures\n $errmsg"
} else {
    puts "Test finished"
}
```

This gives error as

Test finished with failures

make: unrecognized option `--target_board=atmega128-sim"'

Usage: make [options] [target] ...
......

But if I remove the compile.exp from the RUNTESTFLAGS, it works fine.

```
if {[catch {exec make check RUNTESTFLAGS="--target_board=atmega128-sim"} errmsg ]} { 

.....
```

Is it because of the double quotes present in argument RUNTESTFLAGS?
I need to run make check with different RUNTESTFLAGS.
Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 7):

First off, the core of this question is about:

```
exec make check RUNTESTFLAGS="compile.exp --target_board=atmega128-sim"
```

Everything else is just (correct) wrapping. The issue is that you are using Bourne shell syntax above, not Tcl syntax, so the above ends up with RUNTESTFLAGS set to `"compile.exp` (with the quote) and the rest is sent as another argument to make. Not what you want! (Tcl only lets a double-quoted string start at the front of a word; bash is more lenient.) A correct version would be:

```
exec make check "RUNTESTFLAGS=compile.exp --target_board=atmega128-sim"
```

But it's easier and *much* clearer to split that up, like this:

```
set runTestFlags "compile.exp --target_board=atmega128-sim"
exec make check RUNTESTFLAGS=$runTestFlags
```